# Authentication strange behavior with JWT, CakePHP 3 and AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, jwt

I'm facing a strange issue with the authentication using CakePHP and the [JWT](https://github.com/ADmad/cakephp-jwt-auth).

I created a test application and everything works fine than I created a new project (the real project), configure everything equals, but something is wrong.

When I try to request a not permitted api, I'm receiving

```
{
    "message": "You are not authorized to access that location.",
    "url": "\/api\/advertisements.json",
    "code": 401
}<pre class="cake-error"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementById('cakeErr57881c28563e8-trace').style.display = (document.getElementById('cakeErr57881c28563e8-trace').style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none');"><b>Warning</b> (2)</a>: file_put_contents(/home/erick/Projetos/ProjetoX/projetox/6busca/logs/error.log) [<a href='http://php.net/function.file-put-contents'>function.file-put-contents</a>]: failed to open stream: Permissão negada [<b>CORE/src/Log/Engine/FileLog.php</b>, line <b>134</b>]<div id="cakeErr57881c28563e8-trace" class="cake-stack-trace" style="display: none;"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementById('cakeErr57881c28563e8-code').style.display = (document.getElementById('cakeErr57881c28563e8-code').style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none')">Code</a> <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementById('cakeErr57881c28563e8-context').style.display = (document.getElementById('cakeErr57881c28563e8-context').style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none')">Context</a><pre id="cakeErr57881c28563e8-code" class="cake-code-dump" style="display: none;"><code><span style="color: #000000"><span style="color: #0000BB">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$mask&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #007700">=&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">$this</span><span style="color: #007700">-&gt;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">_config</span><span style="color: #007700">[</span><span style="color: #DD0000">'mask'</span><span style="color: #007700">];</span></span></code>
<span class="code-highlight"><code><span style="color: #000000"><span style="color: #0000BB">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #007700">if&nbsp;(empty(</span><span style="color: #0000BB">$mask</span><span style="color: #007700">))&nbsp;{</span></span></code></span>
<code><span style="color: #000000"><span style="color: #0000BB">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #007700">return&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">file_put_contents</span><span style="color: #007700">(</span><span style="color: #0000BB">$pathname</span><span style="color: #007700">,&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">$output</span><span style="color: #007700">,&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #0000BB">FILE_APPEND</span><span style="color: #007700">);</span></span></code></pre><pre id="cakeErr57881c28563e8-context" class="cake-context" style="display: none;">$level = &#039;error&#039;
$message = &#039;[Cake\Network\Exception\UnauthorizedException] You are not authorized to access that location.
Request URL: /api/advertisements.json
Referer URL: http://localhost:85/
Client IP: 127.0.0.1
Stack Trace:
.... and a long stacktrace
```

When it's supposed to return only:

```
{
    "message": "You are not authorized to access that location.",
    "url": "\/api\/advertisements.json",
    "code": 401
}
```

I really don't know why it is returning the block of HTML code and not only the JSON return.

Because of this piece of HTML code the method to redirect to the login:

```
responseError: function (rejection) {
   if(rejection.status === 401) {
      var stateService = $injector.get('$state');
      stateService.go('login');
   }
   return $q.reject(rejection);
}
```

doesn't work, because cannot serialize the response

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 126
```

Anyone have any idea? (I can put more pieces of code if needed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

I find the problem. The application hadn't permission to write in the error.log. So it was returning the error that couldn't write the log to the erro.log file.

Give the right permissions to the file solve everything.